# How to open a raw image?

Tags: gimp, imagemagick, raw, camera-raw

I've installed Gimp via brew on my Mac. This is the error when trying to open a raw image:

[image]

I've installed `ufraw` (also via brew). That is supposed to integrate with Gimp, but I didn't notice any difference. There is now a `ufraw-batch` executable on the command line, but no one for `ufraw`. From what I read, I thought I should be able to run `ufraw` standalone; but I don't know how.

I also tried to convert the image with imagemagick:

```
magick I0000002.raw image.jpg
```

but that didn't work either:

> magick: Unsupported file format or not RAW file `I0000002.raw' @ error/dng.c/ReadDNGImage/516.

Lastly I tried RawTherapee, but that doesn't seem to have a working file selection dialog: I couldn't even navigate to the file I wanted to open!

Is there an easy, free way to open/convert a raw image on Mac or Linux?

Comment: Check for Adobe Digital Negative Converter (for Mac, there is no linux version). Convert to DNG. And almost any image editor will be able to open it: https://helpx.adobe.com/bg/camera-raw/using/adobe-dng-converter.html

Comment: Raw [is not a single well-defined format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format). If anything is able to open your raw image, it's only because it knows this particular raw format. Can you tell anything about the raw image? What device is it from? Currently your question says nothing about the file itself, it may be any raw format. There is no information to even take an educated guess. Answers may be "try this" and if anything works then it will be because we're lucky to guess right. Unless you say something useful about the raw file.

Comment: The image comes from an ultrasound scanner. I don't know the brand; would've to go to the doctor to ask. Interesting though, I didn't know that raw wasn't well-defined.

Comment: To make it clear: your (or any) raw may be well-defined and documented somewhere. The problem is it may be not; and we don't know which raw format it is. Apparently the tools you have used so far also don't know this, they probably don't support this format at all (if they did, then they would be able to recognize it).

Comment: Is there some sort of file header that might shed some light on the format? How can I read that? Are raw images standardized enough to require a file header that specifies the format further?

Comment: It's totally up to the manufacturer. Even if there was a standard, the manufacturer could choose not to follow. There is no obligation to follow anything. Particular raw format is designed as internal to some hardware+software ecosystem developed by the manufacturer. If any third party tool can open it, treat it as a bonus. In Linux the `file` command may tell you something (see `man 1 file`), but there is no guarantee it will be something useful.

Comment: `file` did not tell me much: `I0000002.raw: Hierarchical Data Format (version 5) data`.

Comment: Did you follow this clue? The file may or may not really be [HDF5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Data_Format); but in my Ubuntu the description of `h5utils` package says "HDF5 is a format for storing scientific data", then there is `silx`: "toolbox for X-Ray data analysis". Therefore I think an image from an ultrasound scanner *may* be genuinely in this format.

Comment: There's a chance that this is raw pixels as provided by the scanner's imaging component - GIMP has a plug-in for this, which is invoked by files having a .data file name extension, but you can also select it manually in the file open dialog. You will need to know some additional information about the file, though - the data type of the raw pixels (color? gray? how many bits?), imge width and height in pixels, and the length of the offset to the actual image data (which could e.g. be preceeded by a file header).

Comment: If you'd care to share the file, using something like Dropbox or Google Drive, and anything you know about it, it may be possible to help you better. Useful info would be the name and a link to the device that created the image, the images width and height in pixels, whether it is colour or grayscale, whether it is 8-bit, 10-bit, 16-bit etc.